# Magento 2: What are the "top level tags" in a Module Layout Handle XML File Called?

Tags: php, layout, xml, magento2

In Magento 2, layout handle XML files introduced  a few **new** top level tags (`body`, `head`, etc)

```
<page>
    <body>
        <!-- ... -->
    </body>
    <head>
        <!-- ... -->
    </head>
</page>
```

These tags trigger extra programatic node processing when Magento is loading and parsing the layout update XML files.  For example, the `body` tag's extra processing happens in the following files

```
./lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Page/Config/Generator/Body.php
./lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Page/Config/Reader/Body.php
```

From the point of view of a module or theme developer **using** the system -- what are these new top level tags called?  i.e. in Magento 1, the top level tags (under the root tag) were layout `handles`, and handles contained `block` and `reference` instructions.

i.e. In Magento 2, each individual module layout handle XML file name is a handle, each top level tag (under the root `page` tag) is called a **[BLANK]**, and **[BLANK]** tags contain `referenceBlock` and `referenceContainer` instructions.

What, in Magento 2 parlance, is "**[BLANK]**"

Comment: Does it need a special name? Wouldn't it suffice to just call them page elements?

Comment: According to http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html they seem to refer to it as `<body> section` and `<head> section`

Comment: @fooman Giving important elements of a system names makes it easier to talk about the system, teach the system, and reason about the system.  Example -- "The string you pass into the `getModel`, `helper` or `createBlock` methods that Magento uses to lookup a PHP class name" vs. "The class alias".  Which would you rather read in a tutorial over and over again?

Comment: @R.S. I'm not sure that description completely covers is -- it answers the question for the specific body and head tags, but Magento 2 also processes several other top level nodes in layout files, like `html`, `move`, `uiComponent`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special name at present. `<body>` holds content intended for the body of the page, `<head>` holds content intended for the head of the page. The tags were added to try to help conceptual separation. You put blocks and containers in the body, you put CSS references in the `<head>`.

So `<body>` element and `<head>` element?

Comment: Thank you -- marking this a "best answer" for now, as there's not an answer.  Grain of salt, etc, but If possible, I'd pressure the team behind the layout DSL to formalize a naming convention and structure.  From the point of view of a designer/developer using this system, having layout XML file where sometimes the first child of the root tag is an action and other times it's one of these special parsing context tags is level of abstraction too far. If the system can't be explained it's likely to be abused.